# How to invoke a method with parameter from link

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I have a method in the backing bean that takes a Question object as parameter. I want to pass the question variable in the datatable as argument in a method that is invoked when a user clicks on a button/link. However I only get error in EL when I am trying `#{bean.deleteQuestion(question)}` how can I do this?

```
        <p:dataTable value="#{bean.questions}" var="question"
            id="questionTable" paginator="true" rows="15"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="15,25,50" paginatorPosition="bottom">
            <p:column sortBy="#{question.id}">
                <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{question.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{question.description}">
                <f:facet name="header">Description</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{question.description}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Operations</f:facet>
                <h:link value="Show" outcome="pretty:showQuestion">
                    <f:param name="id" value="#{question.id}" />
                </h:link>
                    &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
                    <h:link value="Edit" outcome="pretty:editQuestion">
                    <f:param name="id" value="#{question.id}" />
                </h:link>
                    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                    // HERE I WANT A DELETE LINK/BUTTON !
                </p:confirmDialog>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Where is the stacktrace? I don't see where you are calling `#{bean.deleteQuestion(question)}` in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *However I only get error in EL when I am trying `#{bean.deleteQuestion(question)}`*

It's unfortunate that you didn't share the exact details about the "EL error" and the code of your attempt (in future questions, you should really do).

I assume that you tried

```html
<h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{bean.deleteQuestion(question)}" />
```

and that it's *actually* your IDE which incorrectly shows a warning/error on that and that you didn't bother to try to run it anyway. Based on your question history you're using Glassfish 3 on which passing method arguments by EL should work perfectly fine. If it's indeed your IDE which jerked on that line, just run it anyway. If it indeed works fine, reconfigure your IDE's validation settings or install a better JSF/EL plugin.

Or if you actually got an `ELException` during runtime, then it can only mean that your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 2.5 instead of Servlet 3.0. Passing method arguments in EL is only supported since EL 2.2 which is part of JSP 2.2 / Servlet 3.0.

Note that the command link should have a `<h:form>` parent. Make sure that you've one; you can put it around the `<h:commandLink>` or the `<p:dataTable>`. Also make sure that the `#{bean}` properly preserves the `questions` for the request of the form submit. Easiest is to put it in the view scope.